# What web server do you use with Go for web service?

Tags: go

If I wanted to create a web service using Go, what web server would I be using?

My web service needs to interact with Mysql, redis and memcached.  Are there stable libraries for each?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package in the standard library is stable and concurrent (goroutine per client).

```
http.Handle("/foo", fooHandler)

http.HandleFunc("/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
})

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

After reading [Writing Web Applications](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) you will have the necessary skills to write idiomatic web applications in Go.

Comment: @user1361315 Except it's much lighter.